# Adding custom dropdown to Froala editor in an AngularJS scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking for a JS rich text editor without frames, allowing to easily customize its toolbar including custom dropdowns, and if possible AngularJS-friendly, I found the *Froala* editor (V2: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and its *Angular directives* (https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/tree/editorV.2), after playing with *TextAngular* (http://textangular.com), which has no easy way for adding dropdowns.

This editor is well-documented (https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v2.0/docs/examples/custom-dropdown), but I'm using it through the Angular directive, and I'm not sure about how to integrate the code adding the dropdown into the Angular scenario: given that I can retrieve a reference to the editor instance from the options set in my controller (`$scope.froalaOptions=...`), I should first set these options, then define and register the dropdown using the editor instance got from them (`$scope.froalaOptions.froalaEditor`), and finally set the toolbar buttons from the options, including the newly defined dropdown.

Apart from the fact that I'm not sure if I can set the buttons options again after setting them once, this does not work, as at the time I try to define the dropdown the editor instance reference is still undefined. You can find the full repro code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PnqnifGE54vMUzk28Jwf

My test code is here:

```
function MainController($scope) {
  var defaultHtml = "<span style=\"color:red\">Hello</span>, world!";

  function addDropdown() {
    var editor = $scope.froalaOptions.froalaEditor;
    editor.DefineIcon("myDropdown", {
      NAME: "myDropdown"
    });
    editor.RegisterCommand("myDropdown", {
      title: "Example",
      type: "dropdown",
      icon: "dropdownIcon",
      focus: true,
      undo: true,
      refreshAfterCallback: true,
      options: {
        "v1": "Option 1",
        "v2": "Option 2"
      },
      callback: function(cmd, val) {
        console.log(val);
      },
      // Callback on refresh.
      refresh: function($btn) {
        console.log("do refresh");
      },
      // Callback on dropdown show.
      refreshOnShow: function($btn, $dropdown) {
        console.log("do refresh when show");
      }
    });
  }
  $scope.html = defaultHtml;
  $scope.froalaOptions = {
    toolbarButtons: ["bold", "italic", "undo", "redo", "selectAll", "clearFormatting", "fullscreen"],
    convertMailAddresses: false,
    plainPaste: true,
    shortcutsAvailable: ["bold", "italic"]
  };
  // uncomment these to try custom dropdown
  //addDropdown();
  //$scope.froalaOptions.toolbarButtons = 
  // ["bold", "italic", "undo", "redo", "selectAll", "clearFormatting", "fullscreen", "myDropdown"];

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.html = defaultHtml;
  };
}
var app = angular.module("test", [
  "ui.bootstrap", "froala"
]);
app.controller("mainController", MainController);
```

Just uncomment the call to the `addDropdown` function and its following lines to see the error. Other than that, the code works. Could anyone suggest me the right path for the Angular context?

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from both the author of the AngularJS directive and the Froala support team (thanks to both!), so I have no credit for this post, but it did not fit a comment: see https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/44.

Essentially, there is no *Angular-ish* way of doing this: we still need to "run those commands on the global `$.FroalaEditor` object before setting your options for the editor". You can find an updated plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HkWCugpVv6jT3tsgEYGZ

Thus, the function looks like this:

```
function addDropdown() {
    $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon("myDropdown", {
      NAME: "cog"
    });
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand("myDropdown", {
      title: "Example",
      type: "dropdown",
      focus: true,
      undo: true,
      refreshAfterCallback: true,
      options: {
        "v1": "Option 1",
        "v2": "Option 2"
      },
      callback: function(cmd, val) {
        console.log(val);
      },
      refresh: function($btn) {
        console.log("do refresh");
      },
      refreshOnShow: function($btn, $dropdown) {
        console.log("do refresh when show");
      }
    });
}
```

Also, we must remember to set not only the `toolbarButtons` array, which in V2 lists all the buttons that should appear in the toolbar *only* when the width of the editor is >= 1200, but also `toolbarButtonsMD`, `toolbarButtonsSM`, and `toolbarButtonsXS` to define which buttons should be shown at smaller widths.

Comment: Your code contains `toolbarButtons` which has various *options*, then why don't they get showed in the text area toolbar while running your Plunkr?